# Apple account's password and iTunes for Windows gets auto-reset every few weeks

Tags: iphone, itunes, password

I am using my iPhone mainly for calling, chatting, checking mail and browsing the Internet. I almost never use purchasable or downloadable content. I connect my iPhone to my PC and launch iTunes for my PC about once every 1-2 months.

Every time I connect to iTunes:

- I get an error that my password is incorrect and I must reset it.
- After I reset it and access iTunes, I see a completely empty library and all sync settings "reset" to "no auto sync".

What am I missing? I never heard about any Apple's auto expiration policy. And what is the reason for my iTunes to have all "Sync" options switched  "off" each time I visit? Is this some kind of weird way of forcing me to visit it more often?

At first I thought "the think" that everyone thinks in this situation. *It's my imagination, since I am using iTunes so rarely then I am also asked for password on very rare basis and I simply forgot what password I have set previously*. But that's not true.

Breaking all possible security advises, this time I had noted down the password on some piece of paper and hidden it in my shelf. Next, about 2-3 months after I last time visited iTunes for PC, I have launched it again, wrote letter-by-letter my "current" password from that piece of paper and... it was rejected as invalid.

I have also recall that during past 9 months (since I purchased this phone) I have visited iTunes for PC about 6 times and I was forced to reset / change my password... 6 times. Because each time iTunes claimed that it was incorrect. I have also recall that each those six time I had to enable sync "again", because it was turned off once I actually got to iTunes.

Can someone tell me what is going on here?